# How to create an value array for a specific key in ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, dictionary

There are `user` and `user_level` models in our rails app. In `user_level` there is a field called `user_group_id`. The relationship is `user`has_many`user_levels`. We would like to generate an array of the `user_group_id` (in user_level) for a given `user_id`.

For a given user_id, its user_levels could be retrieved as :

```
u = User.find(user_id)
ul = u.user_levels
```

There may be multiple `user_levels` for a `user`. How to create an array of `user_group_id` from `ul` with ruby `map` (or some other ruby method(preferable ruby))? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed looking for `map`

```
user_group_ids = ul.map{|x| x.user_group_id}
```

Or with the shorthand:

```
user_group_ids = ul.map(&:user_group_id)
```

You might also want to have only different ids and no `nil`s

```
user_group_ids = ul.map(&:user_group_id).uniq.compact
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
user = User.find(user_id)
user.user_levels.pluck(:user_group_id)
```

or this,

```
user.user_levels.map(&:user_group_id)
```

The first makes a separate database query selecting just the `:user_group_id`. For example, in MySQL it would call `SELECT user_levels.user_group_id ...`.

The second collects the `:user_group_id` from the fetched `user_levels`.